# Why does my TableLayout not display properly when running on API Level 10 or below?

Tags: android, xml, tablelayout

My app uses a TableLayout to show some data to the user. When I run the app on a device (or AVD) with an API level 11 or higher, the table displays perfectly as intended.

[image: api lvl 11 screenshot]

However, as soon as I use an AVD with an API level of 10 or lower, the TableViews do no longer show a margin, nor do they properly perform the `android:layout_width="wrap_content"`-tag.

[image: api lvl 8 screenshot]

Does anyone know, why this is and how I can fix it? The margins aren't number one priority (it just looks ugly), yet the content-wrapping is: since the table does not wrap the entire content as intended, the user will not get all the information he's supposed to get!

Here is my XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".EvalActivity" >       

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollViewGeneral"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"        
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"        
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"          
        android:background="@drawable/border_surrounded" >

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp" >

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_EvalTableRight"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_EvalTableBottom"
                    android:text="@string/str_EvalNumberOfProblems"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lblProblemsCount"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="@string/lbl_OutputDummyString"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_EvalTableRight"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_EvalTableBottom"
                    android:text="@string/str_EvalCorrectSolutions"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lblCorrectSolutions"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="@string/lbl_OutputDummyString"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_EvalTableRight"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_EvalTableBottomBreak"
                    android:text="@string/str_EvalWrongSolutions"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lblWrongSolutions"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="@string/lbl_OutputDummyString"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_EvalTableRight"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_EvalTableBottom"
                    android:text="@string/str_EvalDuration"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lblDuration"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="@string/lbl_OutputDummyString"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_EvalTableRight"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_EvalTableBottom"
                    android:text="@string/str_EvalAverageDuration"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lblAverageDuration"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="@string/lbl_OutputDummyString"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_EvalTableRight"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_EvalTableBottom"
                    android:text="@string/str_EvalShortestDuration"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lblShortestDuration"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="@string/lbl_OutputDummyString"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_EvalTableRight"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_EvalTableBottomBreak"
                    android:text="@string/str_EvalLongestDuration"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lblLongestDuration"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="@string/lbl_OutputDummyString"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_EvalTableRight"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_EvalTableBottom"
                    android:text="@string/str_EvalAddition"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lblAddition"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="@string/lbl_OutputDummyString"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_EvalTableRight"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_EvalTableBottom"
                    android:text="@string/str_EvalSubtraction"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lblSubtraction"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="@string/lbl_OutputDummyString"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_EvalTableRight"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_EvalTableBottom"
                    android:text="@string/str_EvalMultiplication"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lblMultiplication"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="@string/lbl_OutputDummyString"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_EvalTableRight"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_EvalTableBottom"
                    android:text="@string/str_EvalDivision"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lblDivision"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="@string/lbl_OutputDummyString"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_EvalTableRight"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_EvalTableBottom"
                    android:text="@string/str_EvalPower"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lblPower"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="@string/lbl_OutputDummyString"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_EvalTableRight"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_EvalTableBottom"
                    android:text="@string/str_EvalPercent"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/lblPercent"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:text="@string/lbl_OutputDummyString"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>    

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollViewTable"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"        
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/scrollViewGeneral"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"        
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"          
        android:background="@drawable/border_surrounded" >

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tableViewTable"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp" >

            <!-- 
            CONTENT GENERATED PROGRAMATICALLY! 
            -->          
        </TableLayout>

    </ScrollView>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You haven't posted any images(insert the links in the question, someone like me with more privileges will attach them). Also, please don't prefix your titles with `Android`, the tag at the bottom is enough.

Comment: Sorry, images added as external links to imageshack!

Comment: Are you using different `values` folder for various API levels(if I remember right the ADT makes 3 values folder for a new peoject)? If yes, make sure you have those margin values in the default `values` folder and **not** in the `values-v11` folder.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. No, currently I am using one layout located in the "unqualified" res\layout-folder...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this, you need to set a gravity on your table layout. Since you're using margins on all sides, you probably want `android:gravity="center"`. For some reason, API < 10 just kind of ignores the margin if you don't set a gravity for a `TableLayout`.